# SubmitChanges call not updating data

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, submitchanges

The last few hours I'm trying to find out why I'm not able to update the data in the db using the `SubmitChanges` method.

I'm able to retrieve data normally but when I'm calling the `SubmitChanges` method, the call is executing like for 5+ minutes, then its proceeding without any error but when I'm checking the db, nothing gets updated.

I researched a bit before and some other posts were saying to check if primary key has been declared but that has been declared in fact.

This is the code I'm using:

```
SitesDB sitesDB = new SitesDB(SqlConnection);
Site site = sitesDB.GetSite(ProgramArgs.SiteID);

var records = DB.records
    .Join(DB.Locations.Where(l => l.SiteID == ProgramArgs.SiteID),
       s => Convert.ToInt32(s.store_id),
       l => l.LocationID,
       (s, l) => s)
    .OrderBy(s => s.survey_date_utc);


foreach (var record in records)
{
    record.date_local = ConvertTimeFromUTC(date_utc, site.TimeZoneID);

    DB.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: I did...but I'm still waiting for the SubmitChanges method to be executed, 4+ minutes at this moment @216

Comment: Restart SQL Service, clean/rebuild project, restart Visual Studio, restart computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should profile the database to see whay is happening in SQL.

Are you sure it is the `submitchanges`? Since you have the `SubmitChanges()` inside your `foreach` it will only update one record at a time. That should not be that much of a performance problem unless you have a very large table / lots of indexes etc. etc. You may want to move that outside the foreach. However, that will still do one update per record so it will not be that much faster.

Your problem might be **before** the submithanges. By default, Linq-2-sql is deferred execution. That means your select only is executed in the database as soon as you do your

```
foreach (var record in records)
```

So my idea is that this is your performance problem, not so much the submitchanges.

You would want to see this in the debugger, put a breakpoint on the first line inside the foreach record.data... and test if you actually get there.